# Header CSS with login in panel

Tags: html, css

I wonder how to write CSS to get the effect of the header such as this website:

http://www.seek.com.au/

I copied it HTML but haven't write the CSS that has the same effects. Can anyone help with the CSS?

## Micro Devlopment Company

```
<div class="Login">
    <form id="LoginForm" method="POST" action="">
<div class="HeaderLogin">
        <ul class="hd-login">
        <li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" id="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email" size=40 maxlength=60></li>
          <li><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          <li class="l-column mod-multi-button">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
       <ul class="">    
         <li class="">
             <input checked="checked" id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
             <input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
             <label for="RememberMe">Remember me</label>
         </li>
         <li class="">
              <a href="">Trouble signing in?</a>
         </li>
         <li class="l-column mod-multi-button">
                            <button type="submit" id="hiddenLogInButton" name="action" value="SignIn" style="display: none">Standalone</button>
         </li>
       </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>

  </form>
```

P.S.
I just wanted to know how to align and position those fields in the header of the page. For example, the login part of the header is pretty neat, and it doesn't use  to align it. I am relatively new to css and just want to mimic this style. When I reviewing the css of the website, it seems very complicated and there are so many classes and things like that. Could we simplify the css? I mean, we just keep the HTML and simplify the css so it has no unnecessary rules.

Comment: You can look up the CSS for that site and see exactly how they did it.  Check the HTML source and locate the CSS files.

Comment: You'd have better luck getting help if you asked a more specific question. As @LuFaMa pointed out, you can check the CSS used on the site; it's minimised though, so you'll need to use something like [http://cssbeautify.com/](http://cssbeautify.com/) to make it readable, or else use a web inspector to see what styles are being applied to each element.

Comment: "effect of the header"? Can you be more specific. Do you mean the full width layout, the navigation hover effects/inline menu..? @user2967661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you just want to login element position the necessary code would be:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LLM Title</title>
        <link href="head.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Header">
            <div class="mod-banner">
                <h1 class="AU-Main mod-logo">logo</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div class="mod-caption">
                        <ul class="mod-login">
                            <li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                        <input type="text" id="username" name="email" class="state-inp-sign-in hasPlaceholder" placeholder="Email" title="Email" tooltip="Email" clickev="true"></li>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="state-inp-sign-in hasPlaceholder" placeholder="Password" title="Password" tooltip="Password" clickev="true"></li>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                        <button type="submit" id="logInButton" name="action" value="SignIn" class="mod-button state-button-alternate state-button-exception">Sign in</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                        <input name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
                                        <label for="RememberMe">Remember me</label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                            <a href="./SEEK - Australia's no. 1 jobs, employment, career and recruitment site_files/SEEK - Australia's no. 1 jobs, employment, career and recruitment site.htm" data-lightbox-url="https://www.seek.com.au/Login/RestorePassword" data-lightbox-required="true">Trouble signing in?</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="l-column">
                                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="Register" class="mod-like-a-link" id="RegisterLinkStandalone">or register</button>    
                                        <button type="submit" name="action" value="SignIn" style="display: none">Standalone</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

head.css

```
body 
{
    margin: 0;
}

#Header
{
    position: relative;
}

.mod-caption
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
}

.mod-login
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}

dl, menu, ol, ul
{
    margin: 9px 0;
}

.mod-login li
{
    height: 33px;
    list-style: none;
}

.l-column, .l-column-overflow
{
    margin-left: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.state-inp-sign-in
{
    -moz-outline: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 130px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

button, input, select, textarea
{
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html, button, input, select, textarea
{
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.mod-banner
{
        float:left;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Btw, I also want to have the logo at the left and the login panel on the right, just like the website I mentioned. So do I need to float the logo(<h1>) to left, and float the div that contains all the login stuff(you wrote above) to the right?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I am studying the code now. How did you figure it out? I am kinda new to CSS and just read a book about CSS, but after reading the book and do the examples in it, I find that I still could not design a page layout freely as what I want, just like I didn't write out the CSS by looking at that website. Could you give me some advices? I found many books on CSS just cover some basic part, but they never tell how to implement some real world page layout, just like that site. Any suggestions for how to be good at CSS? Thanks!

Comment: I added site for logo, see code please. For learn programming css I recommend you use debug tools from browser, Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thanks. "For learn programming css I recommend you use debug tools from browser, Chrome or Firefox" -- you mean use Chrome DevTools or Firefox Inspect to inspect the HTML elements on the page, then check out all the CSS rules styling these elements on the right panel?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the css file http://www.seek.com.au/, and have left only the necessary html code for the head, the css I have left as is, and working properly. The code required is:

For head.css download and rename to head.css this file [css](http://www.seek.com.au/Content/css/common.css?v=_GHB0fgqiiF1aEqENnbsioLpi3bnY_pZ-FUdqI4Gu9I1)

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LLM Title</title>
        <link href="head.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="body-home-index Main au">
        <div id="Header">
            <div class="mod-navigation state-horizontal state-sites-nav">
                <div class="l-row">
                    <div class="mod-switch pull-right">
                        <span class="is-selected">AU</span><a title="SEEK NZ" href="http://www.seek.co.nz/?cid=sk:main:au:nav:nz">NZ</a>            
                    </div>    
                    <div class="grid_6 l-h-centered">
                        <ul class="state-subsites-nav">
                            <li class="state-jobs active">
                               <a class="is-active">Jobs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="state-learning">
                                <a href="http://www.seeklearning.com.au/?CampaignCode=SEEK_BANNER_29" title="SEEK Learning">Courses</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="state-commercial">
                                <a href="http://www.seekcommercial.com.au/?tracking=sk:main:au:nav:bus" title="SEEK Commercial">Businesses for sale</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="state-volunteer">
                                <a href="http://volunteer.com.au/?tracking=SKMAU:main+header" title="SEEK Volunteer">Volunteering</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mod-nav-login l-row">
                <form id="LoginHeaderForm" method="POST" action="https://www.seek.com.au/Login/Options?returnUrl=%2F">
                        <input id="Feature" name="Feature" type="hidden" value="Navigation">
                    <div id="loggedInName" class="mod-caption">
                        <ul class="mod-login">
                            <li>
                                <ul class="l-clearfix">
                                    <li class="l-column grid_2 state-ie-fix-grid">
                                        <input type="text" id="username" name="email" class="state-inp-sign-in hasPlaceholder" placeholder="Email" title="Email" tooltip="Email" clickev="true"></li>
                                    <li class="l-column grid_2 state-ie-fix-grid">
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="state-inp-sign-in hasPlaceholder" placeholder="Password" title="Password" tooltip="Password" clickev="true"></li>
                                    <li class="l-column mod-multi-button">
                                        <button type="submit" id="logInButton" name="action" value="SignIn" class="mod-button state-button-alternate state-button-exception">Sign in</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="l-clearfix">
                                    <li class="l-column grid_2">
                                        <input checked="checked" id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
                                        <label for="RememberMe">Remember me</label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="l-column grid_2">
                                            <a href="./SEEK - Australia's no. 1 jobs, employment, career and recruitment site_files/SEEK - Australia's no. 1 jobs, employment, career and recruitment site.htm" data-lightbox-url="https://www.seek.com.au/Login/RestorePassword" data-lightbox-required="true">Trouble signing in?</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="l-column mod-multi-button">
                                            <button type="submit" name="action" value="Register" class="mod-like-a-link" id="RegisterLinkStandalone" data-automation="nav-btn-regSubmit">or register</button>    
                                        <button type="submit" id="hiddenLogInButton" name="action" value="SignIn" style="display: none">Standalone</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mod-banner l-clearfix">
                <div class="l-row">
                    <h1 class="AU-Main mod-logo">SEEK</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps, if not tell me what you asked, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know how to align and position those fields in the header of the page. For example, the login part of the header is pretty neat, and it doesn't use <table> to align it. I am relatively new to css and just want to mimic this style. When I reviewing the css of the website, it seems very complicated and there are so many classes and things like that. Could we simplify the css? I mean, we just keep the HTML and simplify the css so it has no unnecessary rules.